# the numerical method for locally well-posed problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

According to Wikipedia,

If the problem is well-posed, then it stands a good chance of solution on a computer using a stable algorithm. If it is not well-posed, it needs to be re-formulated for numerical treatment. Typically this involves including additional assumptions, such as smoothness of solution. This process is known as regularization. Tikhonov regularization is one of the most commonly used for regularization of linear ill-posed problems.

I wonder is there any typical process for locally wellposed problem for numerical treatment.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you clarify? Usually, choice of numerical scheme or even method depends on the problem in question, or at least what kind it is

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any backgroud knowledge about numerical analysis, I just wonder is there any special process when we numerically treat nonlinear hyperbolic equation which has C1 blow solution like 1-d Euler poisson equation with the negatively large gradient of initial velocity.

Comment: This question is not well posed. Define "locally well-posed", please!

Comment: the case C1 blow solution uniquely exist.

Comment: Sorry to my ill-posed question, after I study more, I will ask more well-posed question than now.